# mysql case statement fails to create a new column

Tags: mysql

Sorry about asking the basics. I am trying to make a new column named new_column as in the code below while keeping the old_column as well. When I run the below query, I do get the results printed out fine on the console, but failed to insert the results to the new_column.

I tried both ways, first creating a column named new_column (empty) and then run the query, and secondly just running the query as below. Both didn't return new_column inserted with integer values. What am I missing?

```
SELECT old_column CASE 
WHEN 'A' THEN 1
WHEN 'B' THEN 2
WHEN 'C' THEN 3 
ELSE 0 
END AS new_column
FROM table_name
```

Comment: I think you need to replace `WHEN 'A'` to `WHEN new_column = 'A' THEN 1`. Try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, and doesn't produce anything except an error message as you've written it here.

If I understand your question correctly, this should produce the output you want:

```
SELECT 
  old_column, 
  CASE old_column
    WHEN 'A' THEN 1
    WHEN 'B' THEN 2
    WHEN 'C' THEN 3 
    ELSE 0 
  END AS new_column
FROM 
  table_name
```

A `SELECT` does exactly what it says it does - it selects the data, but doesn't actually alter it's content.

To *permanently* add a new column and populate it, you'll need to first `ALTER TABLE` to add the new column, and then `UPDATE` that new column's content.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN newcolumn integer;
UPDATE 
  table_name 
SET newcolumn = CASE oldcolumn 
                  WHEN 'A' THEN 1
                  WHEN 'B' THEN 2
                  WHEN 'C' THEN 3
                  ELSE 0
                END;
```

For future reference: If you want help with your SQL syntax, include the actual code you've tried that isn't working, instead of inventing something as you go or re-typing. With SQL-related questions, it's almost always a good idea to post some sample data and the output you'd like to obtain from that data, along with your *actual* SQL code trying to produce that output. It makes it much easier to help you when we can understand what you're trying to do and have samples to use.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will keep that in mind for future questions. Regarding the answer you suggested, it returns the results fine in the console screen but not reflected in the table. I can see the new_column with intended integer values in the console screen and in terminal, but when I look at the table the new_column field is just empty - none of the result is inserted to the field.

Comment: The solution which you added later is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it possible to make a virtual column out of it? So every time I want to do it I dont need to remember what to write?